# InvalidClassException error while deserializing session data

Tags: java, spring, serialization, weblogic, apache-commons

Here is the calling code:

```
Object attribute = session.getAttribute(name, scope);
```

and this throws the following eror:

```
Could not deserialize session data.
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.commons.lang.time.FastDateFormat; local class  incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1, local class serialVersionUID = -7186497712641044641
```

The environment is Weblogic. The Web application is a spring portlet. I'm trying to understand how to fix this issue.

Comment: Check whether two version of FastDateFormat with different serialVersionUID. Make sure serialization and deserialization using the same serialVersionUID.

Comment: @Loc Naive question. I think I did not properly understand the issue. I know that its failing during deserialization (loading session data into the application?). So it's unable to cast one of the session values to FastDateFormat? So in this situation, which two classes of FastDateFormat are you referring to?

Comment: Do you have 2 versions of a jar on the classpath or use 2 different versions when serializing vs. deserializing?

Comment: The exception say clearly that you used a version for serialization and another version for deserialization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had to add the commons-lang to the "preferred application packages" section of weblogic.xml to get this fixed.

```
<container-descriptor>
    <prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>org.apache.commons.lang.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>
    <optimistic-serialization>true</optimistic-serialization>
    <show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</show-archived-real-path-enabled>
</container-descriptor>
```